# consulta en mysql con where

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

hola estoy tratando de hacer la siguiente consulta:
Encuentra aquellas familias que tienen al menos 3 hijos, y con edad máxima inferior a 10 años.

(todos los campos que pide la consulta esta en la misma tabla)

tengo esto:

```
>SELECT * FROM familias WHERE familias.Num_Hijos >=3  
and familias.Edad_HijoMayor =< 10
```

pero no sé la sintaxis correcta.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow. Coloca la estructura de tus tablas, para ayudarte con tu consulta.

Comment: Saludos. La sintaxis que muestra es correcta. ¿Algún error al ejecutar la consulta?

Comment: Esto no funciona como los foros, no tienes que poner **SOLUCIONADO** en la pregunta, sino marcar la respuesta que ha servido como solución. Ten en cuenta que este sitio está pensado para que futuros usuarios con el mismo problema sepan referirse a la(s) respuesta(s) adecuada(s). Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: uy, pues perdón por existir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado tu enunciado **Encuentra aquellas familias que tienen al menos 3 hijos, y con edad máxima inferior a 10 años.** , yo solo dejaría la consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM familias WHERE familias.Num_Hijos >= 3  
and familias.Edad_HijoMayor < 10
```

Es decir `familias.Edad_HijoMayor < 10` por que así solo va a tomar en cuenta a los hijos que tengan menos de 10 años, por que tu habias puesto **=<** que no es una sintáxis válida

Los operadores de comparación deben ser así

1. <= que es menor o igual
2. > = que es mayor o igual
3. < que es menor que
4. > que es mayor que

Comment: Shadow haciendo como dices se excluirían los hijos que tengan `10` años. Si en los resultados deben quedar reflejados los **hijos de 10 años inclusive**, entonces debe ponerlo así: `<= 10` o bien así: `< 11`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano es que me guié en el enunciado donde dice **con edad máxima inferior a 10 años** lo cual se interpreta que no se tome en cuenta a los de 10 años

Comment: Sería bueno que @BetRosas precise si en los resultados deben *incluirse*  los hijos con 10 años o si deben *excluirse*.

Comment: entiendo @A.Cedano estaré a la espera de esa actualización y de ser necesario lo actualizo en la respuesta o no se que sea mejor borrarla?

Comment: No amigo borrarla no, tu respuesta da en el clavo del error que era **tener los operadores al revés**. En cuanto a lo otro, sería cuestión de que el OP precise con exactitud cuáles son los resultados esperados.